# getContent from a page and comparing if its equal another page php

Tags: php

Is this a good way of comparing the content from a page. The page content is json.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$f = $client->request('GET', 'url json 1');
$result1 = $f->getBody()->getContents();

$s = $client->request('GET', 'url json 2');
$result2 = $s->getBody()->getContents();

 if($result1 === $result2){
 ....
 } else {
 ....
 }
```

This doesnt work properlly, if the content is equal to the other content, it still return validations inside the else statement instead of the if statement.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: How are we supposed to tell you what you're doing wrong if that's not your actual code?

Comment: @Patrick its the same thing.I just dont want to write my actual code. if there is an error in my code then there would be an error here too.

Comment: If you don't want to provide your actual code, then people probably aren't going to want to provide an answer.  Sorry, but that's just kinda how it works.

Comment: $vr = "1"; $tr = "2"; $val = $vr + $tr (real code $tmp = "2"; $tmp1 = "5"; $val = $tmp + $tmp1)
Regardless if its real code or not, can you spot error in both version?

Comment: `$arraysAreEqual = (json_decode($result1, 1) == json_decode($result2, 1); // TRUE if $result1 and $result2 have the same key/value pairs.`

Comment: So now instead of being upfront about the fact that this is just fake code, you're hiding that from people.  Removing the text that explains that doesn't change anything.  Good luck here mate, it's not going to go well for you.

Comment: @Patrick can you answer my above statement?

Comment: @lukeDS Refering to the php doc, depends of where your object is created the "===" can return false. Have you tried the "==" ?
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php

Comment: @Nico yes didnt work either :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For string binary comparison, I prefer to use `strcmp($result1,$result2)` and check if the result is equal to zero in both type and value.

If I have to ignore the case, I use `strcasecmp($result1,$result2)`.

You can try above functions and/or try using `==` instead of `===`. That's my point of view.